# Excel 2013 - How to delete duplicate phrases from a single cell

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a novice when it comes to VBA, Macros and Modules, so please include specific steps. How do I delete duplicate phrases from a single cell, such as the following:

```
"Brotherhood Of Man - United We Stand Brotherhood Of Man - United We Stand"
```

I want to be left with:

```
"Brotherhood Of Man - United We Stand"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex with a backreference to match duplicated words or phrases. The pattern `^(.+)\s*\1$` will match any duplicating phrase with optional whitespace in between.

```
Const strText = "Brotherhood Of Man - United We Stand Brotherhood Of Man - United We Stand"

Dim re
Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
re.Pattern = "^(.+)\s*\1$" 

If re.Test(strText) Then
    Debug.Print re.Replace(strText, "$1")
End If
```

Output:

```
Brotherhood Of Man - United We Stand
```

**Edit**, with respect to comments:

To check every cell in column A, add a subroutine to your worksheet that iterates each cell and sends the cell value to the regex parser. For example, to run it for the range `A1:A100`:

```
Sub UpdateCells()

    ' Create our regex. This will never change, so do it up front.
    Dim re
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    re.Pattern = "^(.+)\s*\1$" 

    ' Check every cell in a particular range.
    Dim r As Range
    For Each r In Range("A1:A100")
        If re.Test(r) Then
            r = re.Replace(r, "$1")
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you.  Please tell me what a "regex with a backreference..." is, and how do I enter the VBA code; into a Macro?, or into a Module?

Comment: A regex is a [regular expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). A backreference is when a part of the pattern refers back (hence, "backreference") to an earlier match. You can add the code to whatever worksheet contains your text. Just replace `strText` with whatever cell you need to test/update.

Comment: Okay; so I went to Sheet1 and clicked on Developer > View Code and entered your script into Sheet1 (Code).  However, I don't know how to replace strText since every cell in column A needs to be checked for duplicate phrases.  Once again, thank you for your help.